# Como actualizar una base de datos desde Qt?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, sqlite, qt

Tengo un programa que abre una base de datos y presenta la base de datos a través de un modelo en una vista tabla en Qt.

Soy capaz de añadir y eliminar filas en mi base de datos a través de unos botones que activan la acción y unos cuadros de texto donde meter la información.

Pero ahora quiero poder actualizar los datos directamente desde la tabla de mi vista, hacer doble click en una casilla, editar el dato, y al dar a enter que el cambio se mantenga.

Consigo acceder a la casilla de la tabla y editar el dato, pero **no se como hacer para que al dar a enter ese cambio se mantenga. ¿Qué puedo hacer?**

Aquí las funciones que tengo en mi modelo:

```
 Model_Sqlite(QObject *parent=nullptr);
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override ;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;
    void AddTableToDatabase ();
    void InsertData(QString theName);
    void DeleteRowID(int DataId);
    Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex &index) const override;
    bool setData(const QModelIndex & index, const QVariant & value, int role = Qt::EditRole) override;
```

Y aquí mi funcion `InsertData`en la cual implemento el texto escrito en un `QWidget LineEdit`en la vista a mi base de datos debajo del último insertado y actualizo la vista.

```
void Model_Sqlite::InsertData(QString myName)
{
    //beginResetModel();
    int lastRow = rowCount() - 1;
    //int col = 0;
    QModelIndex theParentIndex = QModelIndex();
    beginInsertRows(theParentIndex, lastRow + 1, lastRow + 1);

    int numberOfLastValue=0;
    QSqlQuery qry;
    if(qry.exec("SELECT id from MyQtTable"))
    {
        qry.last();
        numberOfLastValue=qry.value(0).toInt();

        qDebug()<<"mis último id"<<numberOfLastValue;


    }
    else
    {
        qDebug()<<qry.lastError();
    }

    QSqlQuery query;
    query.prepare("INSERT INTO MyQtTable (id,name)"
                  "VALUES (:id, :name)");
    query.bindValue(":id", numberOfLastValue+1);
    query.bindValue(":name", myName);
    query.exec();

    //endResetModel();
    endInsertRows();
}
```

Y aquí lo que he intentado para dejar que modifique el dato en la tabla de la vista y que al darle enter se quede guardado en la base de datos:

```
bool Model_Sqlite::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role)
{
    if (role !=Qt::EditRole){return false;}
    if (!index.isValid()){return false;}
    if (rowCount()<index.row()){return false;}
    if(columnCount()<index.column()){return false;}

        QSqlQuery qry;
        qry.prepare("SELECT MyQtTable.id, MyQtTable.name from MyQtTable ORDER BY MyQtTable.id");
        qry.exec();

//    QSqlQuery qry;
//    qry.prepare("SELECT id from MyQtTable");
//    qry.exec();
//    int themodifyID=qry.value(0).toInt();
//    qDebug()<<"The id modification"<< themodifyID;

//    QSqlQuery qry2;
//    qry2.prepare("SELECT id from MyQtTable");
//    qry2.exec();
//    QString themodifyName=qry.value(1).toString();
//    qDebug()<<"The name modification"<<themodifyName;

    int numRow = index.row();
        int numCol = index.column();
        qry.seek(numRow);

        QVariant theModification=qry.value(numCol);
        qDebug()<<theModification;
    // emit dataChanged(index,index);

    beginInsertRows(index, numRow , numRow);

    QSqlQuery query;
    query.prepare("INSERT INTO MyQtTable (id,name)"
                  "VALUES (:id, :name)");
    query.bindValue(":id",30 );
    query.bindValue(":name", "themodifyName");
    query.exec();

    endInsertRows();

    return true;
```

}

Y aquí una imagen que muestra cómo es la vista.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estaba intentando cambiar la información usando `INSERT INTO, en lugar de`UPDATE`. Tampoco tenía claro qué índices manejaba y de dónde venían, pero **solucionado**!!

Dejo aquí la función `setData`que es la que uso para que modifique el dato en la tabla de la vista y que al darle enter se quede guardado en la base de datos. Dejo comentarios explicativos a lo largo del código para que sea más fácil seguir lo que he hecho.

```
bool Model_Sqlite::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role)
{
    if (role !=Qt::EditRole){return false;}
    if (!index.isValid()){return false;}
    if (rowCount()<index.row()){return false;}
    if(columnCount()<index.column()){return false;}

    QSqlQuery qry;
    qry.prepare("SELECT MyQtTable.id, MyQtTable.name from MyQtTable ORDER BY MyQtTable.id");
    qry.exec();

    // numRow y numCol me dan la posición del valor que quiero cambio en la tabla
    int numRow = index.row();
    int numCol = index.column();
    qry.seek(numRow);

    QVariant theModification=qry.value(numCol);             //obtengo el valor a cambiar
    qDebug()<<theModification;
    qDebug()<<numRow;                                       //fila de la tabla que cambio
    qDebug()<<value;                                        //valor nuevo escrito en la casilla

    QString oldName=qry.value(1).toString();                //capturo el nombre previo a ser modificado
    int oldId=qry.value(0).toInt();                         //capturo el id previo a ser modificado

    beginInsertRows(index, numRow , numRow);                //digo que solo me actualice fila de la casilla deseada

    if (numCol==0){
        //si el valor modificado esta en la columna 0 significa que tengo que cambiar el id
        QSqlQuery query;
        query.prepare("UPDATE MyQtTable SET Id=? WHERE Id=?");          //actualizo el viejo id por el nuevo id
        query.addBindValue(value);
        query.addBindValue(oldId);
        query.exec();
    }
    else if (numCol==1){
        //si el valor modificado esta en la columna 0 significa que tengo que cambiar el name
        QSqlQuery query;
        query.prepare("UPDATE MyQtTable SET name=? WHERE id=?");       //actualizo el nombre de la fila del id con el nuevo nombre   
        query.addBindValue(value);
        query.addBindValue(oldId);
        query.exec();
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug()<<"That column is not valid";
    }

    endInsertRows();
    emit dataChanged(index,index);                                      //envío la señal de datos modificados
    return true;
}
```